# How to setup node distance in tikzpicture without the arrows to change directions?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to know why when I change the distance to 2.5cm the arrow connecting to the ouput node is in the opposite direction as shown in the second diagram. How can I fix this in order for the length of the arrows to be like in the second diagram?

Sample code for the first diagram:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block1} = [draw, fill=white!20, rectangle,minimum height=3em, minimum width=10em]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2.15cm,>=latex']
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [block1, right of=input] (h_k) {$h(k)=h_1(k)*h_2(k)$};
    \node [output, right of=h_k] (output) {};   
    \draw [->] (input) -- (h_k);
    \draw [->] (h2_k) -- (output);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Sample code for the second diagram:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block1} = [draw, fill=white!20, rectangle,minimum height=3em, minimum width=10em]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2.5cm,>=latex']
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [block1, right of=input] (h_k) {$h(k)=h_1(k)*h_2(k)$};
    \node [output, right of=h_k] (output) {};   
    \draw [->] (input) -- (h_k);
    \draw [->] (h2_k) -- (output);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Just to enforce the previous comment, the two snippets of code can reproduce the two picture, but may be not since the node `h2_k` is not declared at all. So, everything depend on where this magic `h2_k` _is_ placed.

Comment: Yes,that did it. I didn't notice that h2_k was there instead of h_k

Comment: See also [Difference between `right of=` and `right=of` in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386) and [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.